# How to get Aptana Studio to remember git ssh password

Tags: git, aptana

I can't find any guides/information on how to get Aptana Studio's built-in git support to remember the ssh password for performing push/pull operations.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Aptana Studio, actually its the built in GIT program, will look for your SSH key in your C:\Users\UserName.ssh folder on Windows.

NO!. The real path would be

%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa  --> for RSA keys, change the prefix if your key is DSA

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I have my ssh config file ( ~/.ssh/config ) as follows

```
Host github.com
    User MyUsername
    IdentityFile=/home/MyUsername/.ssh/MySshKey`
```

If you have a key with a password, you'll need something like ssh-agent or other app so you only have to enter your key password one time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Aptana is asking for a password because:

- your private key is found and is passphrase-protected
- or because no SSH key is found at all (and SSH defaults back to common authentication)

It also depends on what SSH exe you are using, as this [thread mentions](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/676-git-in-aptana-studio-3-fails-to-recognize-ssh-key):

> Aptana Studio sets `GIT_SSH` environment variable to it's internal program which handles SSH password/passphrase prompt in common conditions.
>   In case you replacing default `ssh.exe` executable by setting `GIT_SSH` to `plink.exe`, to work with Aptana Studio you also need to set `SSH_CMD` to the same `plink.exe` path.

[By default, Aptana uses](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2772-aptana-cannot-use-git-commands-with-team-conext-menu-but-works-with-terminal#comment_9512008):

```
[path_to_aptana_studio]/plugins/com.aptana.git.core_[version]/os/win32/sshw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio, actually its the built in GIT program, will look for your SSH key in your C:\Users\UserName.ssh folder on Windows.

To see if this key is working.
First the server must have your public key and you set up the correct remote path to the repository. Then try a normal ssh username@host, if you can log in with the ssh key phrase you should be able to start using git to the remote.

To be able not to have to enter the ssh key phrase every time you want to connect to the remote you could either not have a ssh key phrase.

[SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

Or you need some extra program that saves the password and enters it for you. A so called ssh agent.

[Using ssh-agent with ssh](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh)

Maybe if you install [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) and uses this instead of Aptanas Git. Its probably possible to have it save your ssh key phrase. (Not verified!)

Answer (score 0):

The super easy way to do it is just to include it in the url when you're importing the git repository.

```
EG: https://UserName:Password@www.yourserver.com/repo.git
```

Of course, you'll only want to use this trick with https urls.

Comment: This is a recommendable solution for `clone`, because the password won't be stored (afaik). But in my understanding of security it should not be used for `git remote add` because everyone could check your password by entering `git remote show`.