# Aptana Studio freezes when I try to do a push to my repository

Tags: git, aptana, git-push

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 version 3.4.2, on Fedora.

I have a git repository set up and am using bit bucket. I had a project that was already set up with a .git file in there, and I added that project to my workspace in Aptana. What happens is that when I try to push from the options available when you right click on a project and go to "Team", Aptana just freezes. Same when I try to do a pull.

One potential explanation is that, I have no problem pushing/pulling from the console, but when I do that there, I am prompted for a password. No such thing happens when I use Aptana, so how does it know my information to be able to do a push without prompting me for a password? Because it freezes very shortly after I tell it to push, I just see in the corner it says "git push " and then it freezes. Note I'm also using HTTPS to push.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the url you are using (https or ssh), you need first to make sure the git push from the console doesn't ask you for a password, because you have cached your credentials:

- [in a `~/.netrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266/6309) (or `%HOME%/netrc` for windows), that **[you can encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)** if you want to.
  This is more secure than putting directly the password in the url:

  ```
  https://username:password@server/url/to/git/repo
  ```
- [in an `ssh-agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348125/6309) (for the passphrase to be set automatically for you)

Once that works, try again to push from Aptana, as mentioned in "[How to get Aptana Studio to remember git ssh password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10597789/6309)"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't work by editing the netrc for me, but maybe I had the format wrong. I basically wrote in the .netrc file: machine <name> login <username> password <pass> and it still prompted me. However I edited the git config file to include the password with my login, so it was like username:password@repositorysite.com. That ended up doing the trick.

Comment: @AJ_507 good, I have added that possibility in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, it was this answer that led me to the right path in order to get what was needed.